# Accessing Docker Container on Centos Server

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache, docker

I've managed to deploy a Django app inside a docker container on my personal Mac using localhost with Apache. For this, I use docker-compose with the build and up commands. I'm trying to run the same Django app on a CentOS server using a docker image generated on my local machine. Apache is also running on the server on port 90.

```
docker run -it -d --hostname xxx.xxx.xxx -p 9090:9090 --name test idOfImage
```

How can I access this container with Apache using the hostname and port number in the URL? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From other containers the best way to access this container is to attach both to the same network and use the container's `--name` as a DNS name and the internal port (the second port from the `-p` option, which isn't strictly required for this case); from outside a container or from other hosts use the host's IP address or DNS name and the published port (the first port from the `-p` option).

The `docker run --hostname` option isn't especially useful; the only time you'd want to specify it is if you have some magic licensed software that only ran if it had a particular hostname.

Avoid `localhost` in a Docker context, except for the very specific case where you know you're running a process on the host system outside a container and you're trying to access a container's published port or some other service running on the host.  Don't use "localhost" as a generic term, it has a very specific context-dependent meaning (every process believes it's running "on localhost").

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As a follow up to your suggestion, since the container represents a Django application, I want to access it externally. Do I need to add the published port to ip tables on the server? An example with some code on how to configure this would be really helpful. Thanks.